# Vote 5 time from cookie

Tags: php, mysql

i need to allow vote from cookie 5 times. Set IP to DB i can't do, because people sit in network with same remote adress.

One time i check like this:

```
if( $dif_cookies == 1 ) //from DB
        if($_COOKIE["m_questioning3-$external_id"] == $external_id) {
            $q_show_status = 3;   
        }
```

But i need allow 5 times, how? thank you

Comment: Give each cookie a unique name in stead of IP-number, and store that name in the database for comparison

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dear Haroldas,

```
    if(!isset($_COOKIE["m_questioning3-$external_id"])){
          $_COOKIE["m_questioning3-$external_id"]["count"] = 1;
    }else{
          $_COOKIE["m_questioning3-$external_id"]["count"]++;
    }

    if($_COOKIE["m_questioning3-$external_id"]["count"]<=5){
          your work
    }
```

it will work. Please check it.

Comment: how can i set cookie after submit?

now im do like that:

setcookie("m_questioning3-$form_id", $form_id);

$external_id equal $form_id

Answer (score 0):

thanks for help, but i found solution himself:

im sending post after vote submit and set the cookie:

```
if (isset($_COOKIE["m_questioning3-$form_id"])) {
    if ($_COOKIE["m_questioning3-$form_id"] <= 5)
        setcookie("m_questioning3-$form_id", (int)$_COOKIE["m_questioning3-$form_id"]+1);
} else {
    setcookie("m_questioning3-$form_id", 1);
}
```

in form cheking the cookie value:

```
if ( $dif_cookies == 1 )
    if($_COOKIE["m_questioning3-$external_id"] >= 5) {
        $q_show_status = 3;  
} else {           
    switch ($q_form_type) {
        //... bla bla bla ...
}
```